# Can't show another checkbox by clicking a checkbox dynamically & individually

Tags: php, checkbox, dynamic, hide, show

I have a first checkbox with a list of several schemas.

Want I want to do is simple:

When I check a schema, I want to make appear his individual div "list-right" right below, which is ANOTHER checkbox.

Here is my code :

```php
<div>

    <div>

        <h4>Select your schema(s) :</h4>
        <div id="list-schemas">
            <?php
                foreach ($schemas as $elt) {
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="schemas[]" value="' . $elt->getSchema() . '"/>' . $elt->getSchema() . '<br />';
                }
            ?>
        </div>

    </div>

    <h4>Privileges on tables by selected schemas :</h4>
    <div id="div-privileges">

        <?php
            foreach ($schemas as $elt) {
                echo '<div class="list-right" id="' . $elt->getSchema() . '">';

                    echo '<label for="list-right">' . $elt->getSchema() . ' :</label><br />';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[' . $elt->getSchema() . '][]" value="REVOKE"/> REVOKE ? <br />';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[' . $elt->getSchema() . '][]" value="ALL"/> ALL PRIVILEGES ? <br />';
                    echo '<hr>';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[' . $elt->getSchema() . '][]" value="SELECT"/> SELECT ? <br />';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[' . $elt->getSchema() . '][]" value="INSERT"/> INSERT ? <br />';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[' . $elt->getSchema() . '][]" value="UPDATE"/> UPDATE ? <br />';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[' . $elt->getSchema() . '][]" value="DELETE"/> DELETE ? <br />';
                    echo '<hr>';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[' . $elt->getSchema() . '][]" value="CREATE"/>CREATE ? <br />';

                echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>

    </div>

</div>
```

I managed to display = 'none' ALL THE div "list-right".

As you can see :

```js
var listRight=document.getElementsByClassName("list-right");

for (var i = 0; i < listRight.length; i ++) {
    listRight[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

What I have without the JavaScript function :
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/38/3/1568790896-capture2.png

What I have with the JavaScript function :
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/38/3/1568790893-capture.png

What I want :
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/38/3/1568790898-capture3.png

But I can't make them appear individually, & dynamically...

Can anybody help me..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's correct, here's the code :

PhP:

```php
<div>

    <div>

        <h4>Select your schema(s) :</h4>
        <div id="list-schemas">
            <?php
                foreach ($schemas as $elt) {
                    echo '<input id="' . $elt->getSchema() . '" onclick="show_checkboxes(\''.$elt->getSchema().'\');" type="checkbox" name="schemas[]" value="' . $elt->getSchema() . '"/>' . $elt->getSchema() . '<br />';
                }
            ?>
        </div>  

    </div>

    <h4>Privileges on tables by selected schemas :</h4>
    <div id="div-privileges">

        <?php
            foreach ($schemas as $elt) {
                echo '<div class="list-right" id="list_right_'.$elt->getSchema().'">';

                    echo '<label for="list-right">' . $elt->getSchema() . ' :</label><br />';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[' . $elt->getSchema() . '][]" value="REVOKE"/> REVOKE ? <br />';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[' . $elt->getSchema() . '][]" value="ALL"/> ALL PRIVILEGES ? <br />';
                    echo '<hr>';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[' . $elt->getSchema() . '][]" value="SELECT"/> SELECT ? <br />';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[' . $elt->getSchema() . '][]" value="INSERT"/> INSERT ? <br />';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[' . $elt->getSchema() . '][]" value="UPDATE"/> UPDATE ? <br />';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[' . $elt->getSchema() . '][]" value="DELETE"/> DELETE ? <br />';
                    echo '<hr>';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[' . $elt->getSchema() . '][]" value="CREATE"/>CREATE ? <br />';

                echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>

    </div>

</div>
```

Javascript :

```
/*Way to display none all the list-right divs*/
var listRight=document.getElementsByClassName("list-right");

for (var i = 0; i < listRight.length; i ++) {
    listRight[i].style.display = 'none';
}


/*function to display block when we click on the right schema*/
function show_checkboxes(schema){
   if(document.getElementById(schema).checked){
       document.getElementById("list_right_"+schema).style.display = "block";
   }
   else{
       document.getElementById("list_right_"+schema).style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to this this dynamically you will have to use a client-side script, like javascript. Add onclick functions to your checkboxes like this:

```
echo '<input onclick="show_checkboxes(\''.$elt->getSchema().'\');" type="checkbox" name="schemas[]" value="' . $elt->getSchema() . '"/>' . $elt->getSchema() . '<br />';
```

Also, change your list-right div to this:

```
echo '<div class="list-right" id="list_right_'.$elt->getSchema().'" style="display:none;">';
```

Then add the show_checkboxes function like this:

```
echo'
<script>
function show_checkboxes(schema){
   if(this.checked == true){
       document.getElementById("list_right_"+schema).style.display = "block";
   }
   else{
       document.getElementById("list_right_"+schema).style.display = "none";
   }
}
</script>';
```

Comment: So, right here if I keep my javascript function + yours : it doesn't work BUT when I remove mine, your function make disappear the "list_droite_"+schema div when I check the correct schema... :/

Comment: As you can see : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/38/3/1568794229-capture4.png

Comment: yes, you have to add style="display:none;" to all divs at the start, check edit

Comment: Where is the result... https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/38/3/1568795902-capture5.png

Comment: As you can see, the code : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/38/3/1568796365-capture6.png

Answer (score 0):

Use this to display the correspondent div

```
<div id="list-schemas">
        <?php
            foreach ($schemas as $elt) {
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="schemas[]" value="' .$elt->getSchema() . '" class="schema"/>' . $elt->getSchema() . '<br />';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
```

and this in your javascript

```
<script>
var schmas=document.getElementsByClassName("schema");

for (var i = 0; i < schema.length; i++) {
    schema[i].onChange = function(e) {
    var schema = e.value;
        if (e.checked) {
            showMe(schema);
        } else {
          hideMe(schema);
          }
    }
}
function showMe(schema) {
   document.getElementById(schema).style.display= block;
}
 function hideMe(schema) {
   document.getElementById(schema).style.display= = none;
}
</script>
```

But remeber to make all list-right divs hidden by using display:none in css

Comment: I followed your advice, but nothing appears... :/

Comment: I edited it, I missed some thing, and don't forget to add class "schema" to your checkboxes